# Marking Point when multiple points exists at same location?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld, geoserver-css-module

I am facing Issue while drawing mark on points. When I am giving a image to points, image is coming only to those points where points are not overlapping.
for example, if three POI exists at exact same location , geo-server is not able to draw to any one of it. 
(Geo-server is drawing only to that POI which exists On-TOP.) 
I am drawing on behalf of attribute value, and attribute value is different for all these three POIs.

I am using geoserver css module to create sld.
I am attaching SLD and CSS as well.

[SLD file](http://www.justrack.in/doc/poi.sld)

[CSS file](http://www.justrack.in/doc/poi.css)

[image]

Comment: we will need to see the sld file you are using

Comment: Hello iant, I have uploaded the required documents. Please help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am facing similar problem and havent found a solution.